# Optional parameter with missing value in MiniZinc

Tags: arrays, minizinc

I am trying to model something similar to a job shop problem.  There are multiple jobs, which can be done in multiple ways, which use a varying number of tasks to accomplish the job.

I have set up this data structure to represent that information:

```
enum Job;
enum Option;
int: maxTasks;
set of int: TaskIndex = 1..maxTasks;

enum Task;

array[Job, Option, TaskIndex] of opt Task: jobOptions;
```

If `jobOptions[j, o, index]` exists, it is the `index`th task of option `o` of job `j`.  If it is missing, that option for that job does not use the maximum number of tasks, and this is one of the empty slots.

I am failing to see how I can initialize this array.  If it was a 2d array, I could do

```
jobOptions = [|
    T1, T2 |
    T3, <>
   |];
```

Since it is 3d, want to do something like

```
jobOptions = array3d(Job, Option, TaskIndex, [
    % Job 1
    T1, T2, % Option 1
    T3, <>, % Option 2
    % Job 2
    T2, T4, % Option 1
    <>, <>, % No second option
   |];
```

However, this fails, because there are three versions of array3d, which take arrays of `(par) int`, `var int` and `var opt int.`  I need a fourth version, taking `(par) opt int`, since `<>` is of type `var opt int`.

I initially tried to do something like

```
array[Job] of array[int] of array[int]: jobOptions
```

to make a "non-square" array, but if that if feasible, I was not able to figure out the correct syntax.

Is there a way to initialize a 3d parameter array with missing optional elements?  Alternatively, is there a better way to present this data?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: The issue has been resolved on the `develop` branch of the MiniZinc compiler. In the next release, `>2.1.6`, it should be possible to use the `array3d` function for optional parameter types.

---

The `array3d` function for `opt` parameters is a feature that is currently missing in the compiler. I would suggest creating an Issue in the GitHub repository: https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc/issues

Normally I would suggest changing the type to its variable counterpart as an alternative (`array[Job, Option, TaskIndex] of var opt Task: jobOptions;`). Although this is not ideal for type checking, it can still be assigned like the parameter version (and will work with the current version of array3d). Furthermore, assigned variables will behave as parameters in the compiler. If you get into any problems with the type checker you could always call the `fix` intrinsic to bind it to a parameter.

However, when I tried this locally it seems I'm running into a segmentation fault in the compiler. I would suggest you try the same and if you run into the same problem, then, again, report the issue in the GitHub repository: https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc/issues